# How to create a multi-line dict value in Python with embedded curley brachets?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, escaping

I have the case where I am building a python dict which contains strings from the style sections of a bunch of web pages. The idea is to be able to set the style for a page from the key of the associative array (dictionary). The brackets that are part of CSS directives do not pass the Python parser, even if they are doubled and within a quoted string.

The open and close brackets are doubled. It appears that the problem is with the layout of the
string. Python sees EOL and raises a syntax error when it should proceed to eat the string until
the next quote. I tried changing the double quotes to single quotes, no chance.

```
 File "styles.py", line 2
    "<style> body {{ margin: 5%; background: lightyellow; }}
                                                       ^
 SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

The first elem of the dict is: This is Python 3.4

```
$ head -15 styles.py
styles = { "lightyellow":
    "<style> body {{ margin: 5%; background: lightyellow; }}
    #nav {{list-style: none;}}
    #nav li{{
       display:inline;
    }}
    #nav a{{
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px;
        color: #000;
    }}
</style>",
....
```

Any suggestions? Should I join all the lines together and replace the white space with UNIX escapes,
tabs and newlines?

Comment: You either need multiline strings (`"""`) or to open and close the quotes on each line and let Python concatenate them by default.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That should have been an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You. I have confirmed that triple quoting the multiline values does work. Please note that the
items appear in reverse order.

$ python3 paras.py

dict_keys(['item2', 'item1'])
dict_values(['\nThis is yet another item\nhaving a multiline value\nin a python dict.\n', '"\nthis is line one\nthis is line 2\n\nthis is a third line\nof a multilined value\n'])
Bruces-MacBook-Pro:~ brucesalem$ cat paras.py

paras = {'item1':""""

this is line one

this is line 2

this is a third line

of a multi lined value

""",
'item2':"""

This is yet another item

having a multiline value

in a python dict.
"""}

print(paras.keys())

print(paras.values())